# Kubernetes Persistent Volume : Can I use env variables or configMap for value provisioning ? if yes then how?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

Here is my Persistent Volume YAML config, where I want to set **server** value from env or configMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: auth-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 500Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual
  nfs:
    path: /nfs/auth
    server: 192.168.10.104 # <ip address from env or config ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scenarios like yours, building a helm chart will be a better approach.

Comment: I managed to add it with a helm chart value.
But is there a way to get the server from a Configmap, a Secret or a variable somewhere when the PV is applied?